# Passing unique input values through ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been looking for the answer from the past 2 weeks now.My Problem is I have a PHP foreach loop, In my foreach loop I am having div tags as a row of each data fetched from the database. Each div rows has HTML input elements and a button to submit those input values to a DB through an ajax request. The problem starts when I submit the input values of any div row, only the first row values get changes

Now, to debug the problem I an checking whether my input elements of each div row is having the unique id or not. It turns out that my input elements have a unique id.

```
<input type="text" name="id" value='.$id.'>
```

At last, when I console.log() before the ajax call, It turns out that no matter which submits button I clicked only the first div row id is passing through the ajax request.

```
 function launchAjax() {
 console.log($("[name=id]").val());       // debug to check the value of id
 $.post(
 "inbetween.php/",
 {
```

To fix this I changes my code by removing the submit input to a button and passing setting onclick() on button to call the ajax request.

Now when I click on the button to call the ajax function nothing happens, and I get the error in console window of saying launchAjax(() not defined.

My full code:

```
 <?php
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($data as $row) { 
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['no'] ?>"><br>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label>XYZ Question</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="NO">NO
            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="YES">YES
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label>XYZ Question</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="NO">NO
            <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="YES">YES
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label>XYZ Question</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="optradio2" value="NO">NO
            <input type="radio" name="optradio2" value="YES">YES
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <button onclick="launchAjax()" class="btn">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
}
?>
```

My full ajax code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 var launchAjax = function () { 
 $.post(
 "inbetween.php/",
  {
      id: $("[name=id]").val(),
      question: $("[name=optradio]:checked").val(),
      question1: $("[name=optradio1]:checked").val(),
      question2: $("[name=optradio2]:checked").val(),
  }
);
}
 });
```

All I am trying to achieve is to save the value of the clicked div row input elements without refreshing the web page.

Please help me I am trying to do this from the past 2 week now.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Do you have same `name` for each input?

Comment: I don't understand what you asked, Sorry. I have the form In the PHP loop and each time the loop runs the name will be same for those inputs. Though my concern was that after clicking on submit I was only passing the first div row input values when I did console.log since I change my submit to button and pass an onclick to an ajax it giving me an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the `onclick` as

`<button onclick="launchAjax()" class="btn">SUBMIT</button>`

When we call the function as above way, they should be defined globally. When we declare any function inside the `document ready` the scope is not global.

To make them global remove `$(document).ready`

```js
  var launchAjax = function() {
  console.log("test");
     $.post(
      "inbetween.php/", {
        id: $("[name=id]").val(),
        question: $("[name=optradio]:checked").val(),
        question1: $("[name=optradio1]:checked").val(),
        question2: $("[name=optradio2]:checked").val(),
      }
    );
  }
```

EDIT: If you want to get it working in document ready, you need to call click even as below

Add an id to the button as bellow

`<button onclick="launchAjax()" class="btn" id="submitBtn">SUBMIT</button>`

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("submitBtn").on('click', function(){
          //Do Your Ajax here
      })
  })
```

EDIT 2: I tried debugging your code and found you are not using `serialize()` method to get all the form data. I have updated the code as below

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  //Call submit of the form
  $("#myForm").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    //HERE YOU HAVE ALL YOUR FORM DATA using serialize() method
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(form_data);
    // Send this form_data wit your ajax post request
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- added FORM here-->
<form method="post" action="/echo/html/" ajax="true" id="myForm">
  <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="10"><br>
    <fieldset>
      <div>
        <label>XYZ Question</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="NO">NO
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="YES">YES
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <div>
        <label>XYZ Question</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="NO">NO
        <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="YES">YES
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <div>
        <label>XYZ Question</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="optradio2" value="NO">NO
        <input type="radio" name="optradio2" value="YES">YES
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <!-- Reomved you function call on click -->
    <button class="btn" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

See if the function is calling now. Hope this helps.

Comment: @stactoverflowsam1 There's only 1 value listed for name=id: `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['no'] ?>">` So that's what it's giving.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you expect it to submit. Can you edit and provide what you expect, especially when you say "first div row"?

Comment: That we can do in Ajax, but first we need to check if something is wrong with form? once you see all the values, then we can debug JS to see where things are going wrong

Comment: Thank you so much @AnandG for helping me out

Comment: @AnandG can you please explain what's in the form action?

Comment: Remove that, not needed